# Caliburn.Micro WPF WindowManager settings not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have to open a child window in a sperate monitor, I tried below code but its giving error.
I couldn't find a proper documentation regarding the WindowManger setting. Please find below the code I have used and it would be great if anyone able to guide how to use the settings in  WindowManager.
Thanks in Advance.

```
        IWindowManager manager = new WindowManager();
        IDictionary<string, object> windowSettings = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        windowSettings.Add("Left", 1920);
        windowSettings.Add("Top", 0);
        windowSettings.Add("Width", 1000);
        windowSettings.Add("Height", 1000);
        windowSettings.Add("WindowState", WindowState.Maximized); 
        manager.ShowWindowAsync(new ChildViewModel(),settings= windowSettings);
```